# Using JOIN to show friends posts

Tags: php, mysql, join

For the past days i've been trying to create a SQL query to show posts between friends. However, I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. For me it looks like the posts repeats itself and behave differently than my intension.

This query is "supposed" to show posts from me and users that are friends with me.

```
SELECT *
FROM bhost_entries
WHERE
  author_u_id='$user_info[u_id]'
  OR author_u_id IN (SELECT follower_u_id
                     FROM bhost_userfollow
                     WHERE following_u_id='$user_info[u_id]')
ORDER BY e_id DESC
```

**Tables:**

```
bhost_entries:     e_id, author_u_id, title
bhost_userfollow:  uf_id, following_u_id, follower_u_id
```

Am I completely off track? Appreciate any thoughts.

**Output (when following 2 users)**

```
Heihei
Aker Brygge-spesial
Vi har oppdatert retningslinjene
Hei, dette er en kladd!
To do list
Testinnlegg
Push Notifications
Californication
Hank Moody
Hei bloggen
Heihei
Aker Brygge-spesial
Vi har oppdatert retningslinjene
Hei, dette er en kladd!
To do list
Testinnlegg
Push Notifications
Californication
Hank Moody
Hei bloggen
```

Comment: Can you show us the output that you get, and that looks wrong to you?

Comment: What do you mean? How should i do that? @Borniet

Comment: Run the query, then copy and paste the output into your answer (assuming the results aren't enormously long).

Comment: What about `SELECT * FROM bhost_entries LEFT JOIN bhost_entries ON (bhost_userfollow.following_u_id = bhost_entries.author_u_id) WHERE (bhost_entries.author_u_id = '$userinfo[uid]')`?

Comment: Something like that? As of now i'm following 2 users, and this is the output. @MarkBannister

Comment: Something *like* that, although you appear to have only included `title` from `bhost_entries` rather than all the columns. You also haven't told us which value of `$user_info[u_id]` you used, or in what way you think this output differs from what you want.

Comment: have you tried "group by" with  "bhost_entries.e_id" ??/ .I think entries are getting repeted here

Comment: Yes, @RavindraShekhawat, it _does_ repeats itself. Tried to add you code at the end of it, before "order by." It still repeats itself somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If I could test it, I would have done this :

```
SELECT e_id, author_u_id, title
FROM bhost_entries, bhost_userfollow
WHERE
  author_u_id='$user_info[u_id]'
  OR (follower_u_id='$user_info[u_id]' AND following_u_id=author_u_id)
ORDER BY e_id DESC
GROUP BY e_id
```

Comment: Every post gets repeated. Any clue?

Comment: That means it works? I've added a group by to avoid repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (e.e_id) AS entry_id,
       e.title AS entry_title, 
       e.author_u_id AS author_id
FROM bhost_entries AS e
JOIN bhost_userfollow AS f
ON (f.following_u_id = e.author_u_id) 
WHERE (e.author_u_id = '$user_info[u_id]' OR f.follower_u_id = '$user_info[u_id]')
```

if i understand it correctly it does the trick. check out here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec3b4/6)